# OPEN_APP_FEATURE with multiple fulfillment modes and distinct entity-sets?

Tags: android, app-actions, android-slices

Is it possible to use the `actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE` built-in-intent to handle both `actions.fulfillment.SLICE` and `actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK` with distinct `entity-set`s for each? I've only been able to get this working when one fulfillment-mode specifies an entity-set for the `feature` param, and the other fulfillment-mode specifies no parameters. What I want is to specify `FEATURE_ONE` and `FEATURE_TWO` for the DEEPLINK fulfillment mode, and `FEATURE_THREE` and `FEATURE_FOUR` for the `actions.fulfillment.SLICE` fulfillment-mode.

I was hoping for a way to make something like this `actions.xml` work:

```
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <parameter name="feature">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>

         <parameter name="otherFeature"> <!-- Not allowed, needs to be `feature` -->
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="SliceEntitySet" />
        </parameter>

        <fulfillment
            urlTemplate="http://www.myapp.com/other-feature{?deepLinkFeature}"
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="feature"
                urlParameter="deepLinkFeature"
                required="true"
                entityMatchRequired="true" />
        </fulfillment>

        <!-- Slice provider -->
        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
            urlTemplate="content://com.myapp.slices.provider/whatever{?sliceFeature}">

             <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="feature"
                urlParameter="sliceFeature"
                required="true"
                entityMatchRequired="true" />

        </fulfillment>

    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
        <entity identifier="FEATURE_ONE" name="first feature" />
        <entity identifier="FEATURE_TWO" name="second feature" />
    </entity-set>

    <entity-set entitySetId="SliceEntitySet">
        <entity identifier="FEATURE_THREE" name="third feature" />
        <entity identifier="FEATURE_FOUR" name="fourth feature" />
    </entity-set>
```

The main problem seems to be that only `<parameter name="feature">` is supported, so you can only specify a single entity-set. I can't combine the entity sets because there would be no way to differentiate between the two fulfillment modes.

Answer (score 0):

From a user experience(UX) standpoint, using OPEN_APP_FEATURE with deeplink and slice fulfillment mode at the same time is not recommended and/or supported. So, as a general recommendation, strive for delivering same experience on the same fulfillment mode.